# #pragma omp parallel for only using 1 thread

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, vectorization

I am trying to implement parallel GEMM using openMP and calling it from python using ctypes. While the code runs, the resource monitor only shows 1 thread is being used throughout the runtime.
The c++ and python code as follows -

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
extern "C"
{
void parallelGemm(const double* a, const double* b, double* c, size_t arows, size_t acols, size_t bcols)
{
#pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i=0;i<arows;i++)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k<acols; k++)
        {
#pragma omp simd
            for(int j = 0; j< bcols; j++)
            {
                c[i*bcols +j] += a[i*acols+k]*b[k*bcols+j];
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

and the python code being -

```
import ctypes
import time
import numpy
from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer
import time

from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libtest.so')
fun = lib.parallelGemm

fun.restype = None
fun.argtypes = [ndpointer(ctypes.c_double, flags = "C_CONTIGUOUS"),
        ndpointer(ctypes.c_double, flags = "C_CONTIGUOUS"),
        ndpointer(ctypes.c_double, flags = "C_CONTIGUOUS"),
        ctypes.c_size_t, 
        ctypes.c_size_t,
        ctypes.c_size_t]

A = numpy.ones((5000, 10000))
B = numpy.ones((10000, 5000))
C = numpy.zeros((5000,5000))
print(A)
print('--------------------------------------')
s = time.time()
result = numpy.dot(A, B)
e = time.time()
print(result)
print('NUMPY.DOT TIME = ', e-s)
print('---------------------------------------')
arows = A.shape[0]
acol = A.shape[1]
bcol = B.shape[1]

s = time.time()
fun(A, B, C, arows, acol, bcol)
e = time.time()

print(C)
print('PARALLEL_GEMM TIME =', e-s)
print('---------------------------------------')
print(C-result)
```

What here could be causing the issue.
TIA

Comment: And you compile and link `libtest.so` how?

Comment: environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS=12`. Followed by `g++ -c -fPIC -fopenmp-simd test.cpp -o test.o` followed by `g++ -lomp test.o -shared -o libtest.so`

Comment: `-fopenmp-simd` does not imply `-fopenmp`, so your code gets vectorised but not parallelised.

Comment: So for vectorization and parallelism it's `g++ -c -fPIC -fopenmp -fopenmp-simd test.cpp -o test.o ` ?

Comment: Using ` g++ -c -fPIC -fopenmp -fopenmp-simd test.cpp -o test.o` does solve the problem

Comment: I have run into another problem, numpy finishes the operation in around 9s whereas the parallelized c++ code does not finish it even in 5 minutes. Now I know numpy uses LAPACK but still c++ should not take this much time,  could anyone please point where the issue is ?

Comment: Have you tried to enable code optimisations with `-O2` or `-O3`?

Comment: Yes, with -O3 it takes 12 times longer. Without -O3, I always kill the operation after 5 minutes and during that time all my 12 threads are pinned at 100% usage, I don't think it should take that much time.. right?